# Pre-Split On a Compound Shard Key

Tags: mongodb

For my needs, I have to do pre-splitting but my shard key is a compound key. both keys of my compound key (k1 and k2) are int and my desired chunk structure is something like this

chunk1 : k1 = minkey to 1, k2 = minkey to maxkey

chunk2 : k1 = 1 to 2, k2 = minkey to maxkey

chunk3 : k1 = 2 to 3, k2 = minkey to maxkey

chunk4 : k1 = 3 to 4, k2 = minkey to maxkey 
...

So what I really want to do is split on the first key only and leave the second key to include all possible ranges but if run this

```
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 1} } );
```

it will fail saying the full shard key is not provided so it makes me to call this

```
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 1, k2:somenumber } } );
```

this command works but the resulted split is bad because it gives me chunks like below

chunk1 : k1 = minkey to 1, k2 = minkey to somenumber

chunk2 : k1 = 1 to maxkey , k2 = somenumber  to maxkey

this is bad because if users insert something a document where k1<1 and k2>somenumber, there is no chunk in the system that covers it and the insert should fail.

How can I create such chunk boundaries with my compound key?

NOTE: One may ask why I have k2 if it is always minkey to maxkey. I have k2 like that to allow further splitting on k2 for same k1 in future if needed be ( and I am sure it will be needed on some of chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it :

```
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 1, k2:MaxKey } } );
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 2, k2:MaxKey } } );
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 3, k2:MaxKey } } );
db.runCommand( { split : "db.mycollection" , middle : { k1: 4, k2:MaxKey } } );
```

By the way, you can never create a situation where a certain range is not covered by chunks since all you're doing is splitting existing ranges. Also note that k2 cannot be from MinKey to MaxKey technically. Your range for the first chunk is going to be `{k1: MinKey, k2: MinKey}` to `{k1:1, k2: MaxKey}`. The next one is going to be `{k1: 1, k2: MaxKey}` to `{k1:2, k2: MaxKey}` and so on

Comment: I tried this but Id did not work and I am constantly getting thisCommand 'split' failed: split failed 

(response: { "cause" : { "who" : { "_id" : "db.MyCollection",
"process" : "blahmachine:27018:1330601796:1743958884",
"state" : 2, "ts" : ObjectId("4f4ffdda58ee8c3d2948d640"),
"when" : ISODate("2012-03-01T22:53:14.839Z"), 
"who" : "blahmachine:27018:1330601796:1743958884:conn3:1105345454",
"why" : "migrate-{ k1: 0, k2: 500000 }" },
"errmsg" : "the collection's metadata lock is taken", "ok" : 0.0 }, 
"ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "split failed" })

Comment: The cluster is fresh and no data is being recorded

Comment: Also, if the limits say maxkey<k2<maxkey, the how would the system know what to do with items whose k2 are less than maxkey?

Comment: There's always a chunk for every theoretically possible value because you're splitting. The above does work, I've tested it on my dev cluster. Your errors are thrown because your balancer isn't turned off and it's probably grabbing the migration lock. I think you should probably read up on the theory a bit more ;)

Comment: As for your last comment, you're misunderstanding what happens at a split. MaxKey<k2<MaxKey is not a situation that can occur obviously, but k1:1, k2:MaxKey < k1:2, k2:MinKey < k1:2, k2:MaxKey is valid.

Comment: oh, I am going to try this again then. I did not know, migration lock could prevent splitting but it make sense if that is the case. thanks very much for the boundaries clarification.